# Run a loop through an array of objects in the $project pipeline of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have used the $group pipeline and inside it, I have used $addToSet which has created an array of objects which contains two values - `{subGenre (string), flag (bool)}`. In the next pipeline of `$project`, I need to run a loop through this array and I need to select only that element of the array where `flag` is false.

So my code looks like this:

```js
let data = await Books.aggregate(
   [
    {
        $group: {
          _id:  genre,
          price: { $sum: "$price" },
           data: {
            $addToSet: {
              subGenre: "$subGenre",
              flag: "$flagSelectGenre"
            }
          }
        }
       }
      ]
    );
```

This would return documents like:

```json
    _id: {
      genre: "suspense",
    },
   price: 10210.6,
   data: [
      {
        subGenre: "Thriller",
        flag: false,
      },
      {
        subGenre: "jumpScare",
        flag: true,
      }
      {
        subGenre: "horror",
        flag: false,
      }
    ]
```

After this, I need to run a `$project` pipeline where I have to only project that element of the data array where the `flag` is true. The flag will be true for only one element.

```js
$project: {
          price: "$price",
          subGenre: {$...... } // some condition on data array??
}
```

The final output should look like this:

```
   price: 10210.6,
   subGenre: "jumpScare",
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

- `$filter` - to filter items from **data** array, where **flag** property is equal to **true**.
- `$first` - to get first item from above array.
- `$getField` - to get value of **subGenre** property of the above item.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "price": 1,
      "data": {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "subGenre",
          "input": {
            "$first": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$data",
                "cond": "$$this.flag"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hWEX8Z0Pz9G)

Comment: How to select that element where the flag does not exist? I am unable to use $exist with cond here. My syntax is similar to yours with difference in $filter - $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $exists: [ "$$this.flag", false ] } } its giving error - Unrecognized expression '$exist'

Comment: `$exists` is not an Aggregate operator. Why didn't you use my solution? `flag` is Boolean anyway, so only the items where `flag` is true will be filtered.

Comment: I want to select the element where the flag does not exist. Actually, the real problem is the flag will be set to true if that element of the array is edited. I need to select the element which was not edited. So I need the element where flag does not exist.

Comment: But you said the opposite in the question. In that case, you can use the `$type` operator: `"cond": { "$eq": [ { "$type":  "$$this.flag"}, "bool" ] }`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$filter` array operator to loop and filter elements by required conditions,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `data` array, if `flag` is true then return element
- `$let` to define a variable and store the above filter result
- `$first` to return the first element from the filtered result, you can also use `$arrayElemAt` if you are using lower version of the MongoDB

```
  {
    $project: {
      price: 1,
      subGenre: {
        $let: {
          vars: {
            data: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$data",
                cond: "$$this.flag"
              }
            }
          },
          in: { $first: "$$data.subGenre" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_HLvg_S60Gp)

---

Another approach using `$indexOfArray` and `$arrayElemAt` operators,

- `$indexOfArray` will find the matching element index of the array
- `$arrayElemAt` to get specific element by specifying the index of the element

```
  {
    $project: {
      price: 1,
      subGenre: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$data.subGenre",
          { $indexOfArray: ["$data.flag", true] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VvCVuXs5KJM)

Comment: Nice solution with `$let`!

Comment: Yeah, there are many ways to do this, yours is also a nice solution with `$getField`.